# MySQL - Select highest values from one column, then re-order based on a second column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I think what I need to do can be done using one query, but I'm really not sure - and I'd like to avoid performing a query and then sorting the resultant array if possible.

Basically, I have one table, which includes the following columns:

> product_name, price, sold

From these columns, I'd like to do the following:

- Select the highest 20 values from the `'sold' column DESC`;
- Order the 20 results by `price ASC`.

Sounds so simple, but can't figure out how to accomplish this to save my life, and SQL is not my strong point. If anyone could help out, it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You can use subqueries for this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
      from t
      order by sold desc
      limit 20
     ) t
order by price asc
```

You have a query that does a bunch of stuff.  I'll call this .  Here is what you do:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
      from (<subquery
           ) t
      order by sold desc
      limit 20
     ) t
order by price asc
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I'm looking for, but I don't understand it fully enough to incorporate it into my current query:

`SELECT DISTINCT(products.prodid), products.product_name, products.unitprice, products.rrp_price, products.description, products.displayoff, products.options, offer_products.offer_text, products.url, products.stock FROM products LEFT JOIN offer_products ON products.prodid = offer_products.prodid WHERE displayoff != '2'$stock_count ORDER BY sold DESC LIMIT 0,20`

How would I add this - where 'sold' is the column I want to grab the 20 highest from? And thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you are looking for:

```
select * from table
order by sold desc, price asc
```